# laravel route naming page not found error 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**hi I have a problem in laravel route... I name my routes like this**

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', ['uses' => 'FacebookController@redirectToProvider', 'as' => 'facebook.login']);
```

**and this is my controller...**

```
public function getRedirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function getHandleProviderCallback()
{
    //notice we are not doing any validation, you should do it

    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    // stroing data to our use table and logging them in

    dd($user);

}
```

**my problem is always error 404 page not found when i click this button**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('facebook.login') !!}">Facebook</a>
```

Thank you :) Im using laravel 5.0

Comment: Just define as `Route::get('my_url', 'MyController@method')->name('route.name')` then in blade `<a href="{{ route('route.name') }}">My Link</a>`

Comment: Your function is named `getRedirectToProvider`, but you're using `FacebookController@redirectToProvider `.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
'FacebookController@redirectToProvider'
```

But your Controller's method is:

```
'FacebookController@getRedirectToProvider'
```

According to your Controller code as posted.

You can always check what your routes are via artisan from the console:

```
php artisan route:list
```

if you're having trouble determining what you've defined or how to access it.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, but my controller function name matches the one of route. It's even showing the route when running `php artisan route:list`, but when trying to access it returns 404 not found.